# Is there some type of way to count the number of columns in an angular grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have an angular grid and want to be able to control how many columns are displayed at one time, for example let's say I want the maximum number of columns displayed at one time to be 5 even if there are more than 5 columns and if the user tries to show more than 5 they wouldn't be allowed to. In the sample code below let's say I only wanted to show 2 columns at a time with all the columns in a select menu so I could switch which 2 columns I look at, could this be done with filtering or through some type of function in javascript/typescript

html

```
<div>
  <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]= "rowData"
    [columnDefs]= "columnDefs" >
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GridRes } from './gridres.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ag-custom';


  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
];

rowData = [
  {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
  {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
  {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];

}
```

Comment: I think you could do two things. Either, always only have two columns in the data, and then manipulate that data, by switching in/out the data. Or make a Pipe, that takes in 2 headerNames and the columns, and returns the two columns matching that headerNames.

Comment: columnDefs is an array, like any other array. you can do what you want with it. just remember to reset the reference each time you change the array, like `columnDefs  = newColDefArray;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a column becomes visible in AG Grid it will fire an event:

```
Events.EVENT_COLUMN_VISIBLE
```

So why dont you subscribe to that event then see if it causes you to have more than 2 visible columns; if it does then swap out an existing visible column with the one referenced in the params for the event?

Comment: do you maybe have an example of how events work for this scenario? If not I understand, I’m also doing my own research of it but not finding many examples